# Duplicate Observations in Stata (data manipulation)

Tags: stata

I have a string variable

```
var1
x
y 
z
```

that I need to "duplicate" and append to give

```
var1 var2
x      x
x      y
x      z
--------
y      x
y      y
y      z
--------
z      x
z      y
z      z
```

where I added the horizontal lines to facilitate reading. Is such an expansion possible in Stata without loops? (I am not sure if "duplicate" is the right term.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two commands:

```
gen var2 = var1
fillin var1 var2
```

See `help fillin` and http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0011